# jQuery gurus, can this code be simplified?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/stapiagutierrez/KKdsb/29/

---

I'm just trying to create my own star rating UI for websites and so far it works just how I want it to, but I'd like to see if I can trim down my code without sacrificing legibility.

Since I'm new to jQuery, maybe I'm doing things the roundabout way.

Any suggestions on where to improve?

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    border-radius:8px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:111px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

li {
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding-top:2px;
}

<ul>
    <li>
        <img class="onestar rating" src="http://i.imgur.com/8LA1i.png" alt="no-star" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img class="twostar rating" src="http://i.imgur.com/8LA1i.png" alt="no-star" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img class="threestar rating" src="http://i.imgur.com/8LA1i.png" alt="no-star" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img class="fourstar rating" src="http://i.imgur.com/8LA1i.png" alt="no-star" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <img class="fivestar rating" src="http://i.imgur.com/8LA1i.png" alt="no-star" />
    </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rating").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("onestar")) {
            alert("Clicked on 1 star!");
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("twostar")) {
            alert("Clicked on 2 stars!");
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("threestar")) {
            alert("Clicked on 3 stars!");
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("fourstar")) {
            alert("Clicked on 4 stars!");
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("fivestar")) {
            alert("Clicked on 5 stars!");
        }
    });

    $(".rating").mouseleave(function() {
        $(".rating").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/8LA1i.png");
        });
    });

    $(".rating").mouseover(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("onestar")) {
            $(".onestar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("twostar")) {
            $(".onestar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
            $(".twostar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("threestar")) {
            $(".onestar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
            $(".twostar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
            $(".threestar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("fourstar")) {
            $(".onestar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
            $(".twostar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
            $(".threestar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
            $(".fourstar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass("fivestar")) {
            $(".onestar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
            $(".twostar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
            $(".threestar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
            $(".fourstar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
            $(".fivestar").attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please also include the jquery code here -- if jsfiddle goes down, this question can't mean much to anyone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was kinda fun, here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KKdsb/30/

**NOTE**: The usage of two `parent()` functions in the `mouseover` handler is subject to your html structure. I'd recommend a class or similar to access the parent `<ul>` element directly using `$(this).closest('.classname')`.

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rating").click(function() {
        var position = $(this).parent().index();
    });

    $(".rating").mouseleave(function() {
        $(".rating").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/8LA1i.png");
        });
    });

    $(".rating").mouseover(function() {
        var position = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
        $(this).parent().parent().find("li:lt("+position+") > img").each(function (i, e) {
            $(e).attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/X68bI.png');
        });
    });
});
```

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/each/
- http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Hey Andre - I edited your answer to swap .parent() for .parents(), but I think .closest() is what you want. .closest() will stop when it hits its first match, where .parents() will continue up the DOM tree looking for further matches.

Comment: Hi Beejamin, I've edited my answer to include `closest()`, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

This is a great candidate for using image sprites. Basically, you put all of your star ratings into a single image file, and move that file around with 'background-position' CSS. The main advantage of doing it this way is that you only ever make one request for the star image - you're not changing the path to the start image repeatedly (which can make things a bit janky and slow, depending on the browser.

Here's an example using image sprites:
http://www.spookandpuff.com/examples/starRatings/starRatings.html

Here's the image sprite I used:

[image: 5 star image sprite]

And here's the HTML, CSS and Javascript:

The HTML is very simple:

```
<div class="starRating">
    <ol class="ratingValues">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
```

It's possible to go without the extra DIV, but that will cause problems on older browsers that don't support multiple-class CSS selectors, so I've left it in.

The CSS is also quite simple:

```
      .starRating {
        width:105px;
        height:20px;
        float:left;
        margin:20px 0;
      }

      .ratingValues {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        list-style:none;
        background:url(starSprite.png) no-repeat 0 0;
      }

      .ratingValues li{
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:21px;
        height:20px;
        text-indent:-999em;
        overflow:hidden;
        cursor:pointer;
      }

      .rating_1 .ratingValues {background-position:0 -20px}
      .rating_2 .ratingValues {background-position:0 -40px}
      .rating_3 .ratingValues {background-position:0 -60px}
      .rating_4 .ratingValues {background-position:0 -80px}
      .rating_5 .ratingValues {background-position:0 -100px}
```

Here, we set up the box to be the same size as one row of stars from the sprite. The list items become squares of the right size (one square per 'star' in the graphic). I've used negative-text-indent to hide the text inside each `<li>`.

Most interesting is the last block. Here, we're adjusting the background position of the sprite depending on the class of a containing element, so, when .ratingValues is inside something with the class of 'rating_3', the background will move to position: 0 -60px.

I bet you can see where this is headed. Here's the javascript:

```
$(function(){
  starRatings = $('.starRating'); //Cache this to make future references faster

  starRatings.each(function(){ //Iterate through each rating, in case there's more than one per page
    var thisRating = $(this),
        triggers = $('.ratingValues > li', this); //More caching

    triggers 
      .hover(
        function(){ //The hover-over event
          var trigger = this;
          thisRating.addClass(function(){
            return 'rating_' + (triggers.index(trigger) + 1); //This sets the class to rating_ + the number of the element (1 - 5)
          })
        },
        function(){  //The hover-out event, just clears the classes
          thisRating.removeClass('rating_1 rating_2 rating_3 rating_4 rating_5');
        })
        .click(function(){ //The click event
          alert('Clicked ' + (triggers.index(this) + 1));
        });
  });

});
```

This finds any element with the class of `.starRating`, and assigns event handlers to the `<li>`s within it. Hovering the `<li>`s assigns a class to the 'starRating' div, which basically tells us what value is selected (rating_1 to rating_5). The CSS kicks in at this point, and moves the background sprite to the right position.

For extra points, you can put a standard anchor, something like this: `<a href="{rateThis?rating=1}">1</a>` within each `LI`, which will fire the request to your server and set the rating over straight HTTP (no javascript). That way, everything still works if Javascript is off.

I hope that's clear enough - shout if you need more help!

Comment: Looks to me like OP is asking for simplification of his code. You upped the complexity but ended up with just as much overall code. Is using images sprites a good idea? Yeah! But your solution seems hardly any better than the original one.

Comment: The OP has said he is new to jQuery, so I have provided an example with lots of explanation, and safeties in the form of caching to allow this solution to be robust and re-useable. It shows some useful techniques for beginners to DOM manipulation, jQuery event handling, and CSS/JS interactions. I stand by it. Reducing complexity is not just about how much code there is - it's about how understandable it is.

Comment: Not exactly the answer to the question, but I think this is a great option. I actually really like the way the stars fill in the sprites, the JS looks a bit slow here. I would totally go for this one in future projects :)

Comment: Another more real problem is: How are you going to display partial scores? I.e. score of 4.5 http://www.amazon.com/Greatest-Hits-2/product-reviews/B005SO6HT6/ref=dp_top_cm_cr_acr_pop_hist_all?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1

Comment: The sprite image can be extended to cover half or quarter points easily enough. It wouldn't be a good solution if you needed to show more precision than that though.

Comment: right, so you would need to edit you image and then double number of your "rating" classes and complexity of the associated code, just to support x.5 values. Mine does it out of the box for any precision.

Answer (score 1):

## Improved Solution

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/UKdsd/)

#### HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="rating"><div class="value"></div></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.rating {
    width:105px;
    height:20px; 
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ9Id.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.rating .value {
    width:0;
    height:20px;   
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ9Id.png) no-repeat 0px -100px;  
}
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var starWidth = $(".rating").width() / 5;
    $(".rating").click(function(e) {
        $(this).find(".value").css({width:(Math.ceil(e.offsetX / starWidth) * starWidth)+"px"});
    });
});
```

Original Solution: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jnX6e/)

---

Pros of this solution over others in this thread:

1. Minimal amount of code, markup and CSS. Very easy to read and
   support.
2. Solves the general design issue in the OP rather than trying to
   patch it with jQuery sugar.
3. Supports floating point scores (simply set the width to value /
   maxWidth)
4. Supports switching between clickable and read-only views by simply
   disabling click event (no need to modify HTML).
5. Following 3 and 4 - it is a single control to display both
   individual user scores and composite score.
6. Smaller image size than required for Beejamin's answer (it only uses first and last rows).
7. No complex DOM manipulations or CSS lookups

Cons: None that I can see.

Cons fixed since last iteration:

1. Removed js dependancy on image width. Now it is dynamically calculated, though I still think it is unnecessary.

Complete and fully functional version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UKdsd/3/). Fancy version with click animation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UKdsd/4/)

Comment: Then how do you detect how many stars to show? Do you check the X position the mouse is in the element? That sounds more complicated with no reason.

Comment: Wouldn't this make for a better comment than an answer?

Comment: @SergioTapia why is it complicated?

Comment: @Flimzy he doesn't have a jQuery problem. He has a general design issue, which he is trying to solve using jQuery, which is pretty pointless exercise.

Comment: Well you have to calculate the width of the each individual star and make sure it's centered.

Comment: This is a simple technique, you're right - my problem with it is that it encodes the width of the stars (which is a graphic/styling concern) inside the javascript. If you ever need to change your star graphics, you need to change the javascript as well, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Another problem with this technique is that it doesn't work at all without javascript - there aren't any elements for the actual 'clicks' at all (just one target, which you grab the X-offset from).

Comment: @Beejamin from my POV everything client-side is presentation layer. If you change star image, you change related js as well. Yes, it does rely on offsets but is MASSIVELY simpler than what OP has, so supportability is hardly a concern here. I don't even know what you mean by your second comment. Nothing works without javascript no matter how you turn it.

Comment: I disagree on the first point - client side is most often broken down into content-layer (HTML), presentation layer (CSS), and behavioural layer (JS). There are big advantages to that distinction, one of which is simplicity of maintenance (you don't have to know behavioural code to change presenation).

Comment: Second point: you can, and should, make this work with straight HTTP by including normal links for each of the ratings `<a href="rateThis?value=1">1</a>` That allows the server to receive the rating submission without javascript, no problems.

Comment: @Beejamin No you can't. Your sample will simply redirect user to the rating URL instead of doing AJAX call on it. Your selection won't work and without it your UI will look broken. Please don't make up absurd scenarios to support a non-point. Neither of presented solutions will work without javascript enabled. Regarding your first comment: that is only an issue if your code is sufficiently complex (which yours is).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4628/discussion-between-beejamin-and-liho1eye)

Comment: Liho, I am happy to give clarification if my scenarios don't have enough detail, but calling them absurd and non-points isn't a nice way of doing it. Remember mate, this is not a critique on you - it's a critique on the merits of various coding solutions. I'm certain this can be achieved without javascript, because I have built such a solution before - I am happy to share it in more detail, if you like.

Comment: Liho - how would you add the ability to show a particular rating when the page loads? For example, if the user has already rated the item?

Comment: @Beejamin Ok, point 1: your solution clearly does not work without js. Simply by the fact that you are using js code in it. You may have built one somewhere else but you haven't presented it. Yet, you go around criticizing mine for exactly the same thing, and then you tell me that I am not being nice to you. That is what I call absurd.

Comment: Point 2: Your solution doesn't do anything more than mine, nor it is any more scalabale. If you really wanted to make it image independant you can always get star width by dividing `div`'s width by 5. I wouldn't bother because it pollutes otherwise simple and pretty code, but Some people choose to overengineer their solutions in anticipation of changes that are unlikely to happen and obstruct the simplistic problem before them. I tend to refer to this http://www.infiltec.com/j-h-wrld.htm in that case.

Comment: Point 3: I haven't written out full code because I don't believe in solving peoples' problems for them. I am always glad to help by giving general direction or pointing out design flaws, which is what I did here. Some people apparently thought I should've just solved OP's problem for him, but quiet frankly I already have one job and not being payed to do his. If you are really desperate for rep, you can do it

Comment: Liho, you make some valid points, but your conversational style is very confrontational, to the point of being insulting, and for no good reason. I've got no interest in continuing this discussion with you.

Comment: @beejamin holy crap, 5 five years later you're still at it... that's some dedication.

Comment: Heh. I got a fresh vote on my answer after all this time. I like editing!